# hyperlink not working caused by overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, overlay

I'm trying to make a website, but when trying to apply a hyperlink to a div, it will not work. I'm pretty sure this is caused by the submenu in the navbar, but if I put in front of it the clickable div, the submenu will only show partially. I don't want to use pointer-events, as it will exclude lots of semi-new browsers (e.g. IE 9, 10). I'll put a link to the website's code, since I don't know which part exactly to attach. The div I want to be clickable is the one that shows "El método":

```
<td style="background-color:#afcea2;" class="tlink"><a href="a&a.html">El método</a></td>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eAbJ2/

Thanks in advanced.

PD: the jquery doesn't work for some reason, that's why it has that strange UI.

I forgot the link, sorry, and thanks again!!

Comment: Rather than explaining your issue in this big chunk of text , a small snippet of code would be nice :)

Comment: also, no link, but code would be better

Comment: Please add relevant code.

Comment: Sorry for the issue, forgot the link. It's on now.Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't apply a hyperlink to a div with full cross browser compatibility. If you truly want this, use javascript

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't put something in a div with class='clear'.
This class makes the height to zero which causes your trouble.